# Matplotlib Annotation Error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda

I tried finding solution to solve this error, but I can't get it.

```
# example data
month_no_list_svc_log = ["Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "March", "April"]
event_count_by_month_list_svc_log = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (10,4))
ax[0].plot(np.arange(len(month_no_list_svc_log)),event_count_by_month_list_svc_log)

# I do this to sort the months name the way I want it to
ax[0].set_xticks(np.arange(len(month_no_list_svc_log)))
ax[0].set_xticklabels(month_no_list_svc_log)

for i, txt in enumerate(event_count_by_month_list_svc_log):
    # the code below generates an error
    ax[0].annotate(txt, (month_no_list_svc_log[i],event_count_by_month_list_svc_log[i]))
```

I get an error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'

Comment: Please provide an example for the data in `month_no_list_svc_log` and `event_count_by_month_list_svc_log`, and the exact line in your code where the Execption occurs. With simple integer lists as the data, this code works for me.

Comment: ok added the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x-coordinate in `annotate` must be a value on the x-axis your provided to `plot`. There, you used the index of the months in `month_no_list_svc_log`, so this would match the value `i` in your `for` loop. Also you can reuse `txt`, here renamed to `count`, in the following way:

```
for i, count in enumerate(event_count_by_month_list_svc_log):
    ax[0].annotate(count, (i, count))
```

Btw: If you want your x-axis to be an `arange` of the same length as your y-axis data, you can just leave away the x-axis parameter in the call to plot:

```
ax[0].plot(event_count_by_month_list_svc_log)
```

Comment: Just a note that when you have more than one subplot, your code for annotate should come after all the subplots have been plotted.

Comment: I now replaced `plt` back with `ax[0]` as it was in your code, now this should work again. I had just previously exchanged it for a test on my side.